# JdbcTemplate queryForMap get() returns null for valid key

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

A simple JdbcTemplate.queryForMap() call on MySQL table yields this strange explainable behavior. The map output returns null for get() and expected results for keySet() and values().

Edited:
-Posted full class code
- Appended query with RowMapper() implementation.

Here's the table schema:

```
create table Product(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(30),
    price decimal(10,2)
);

mysql> select * from Product;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | price |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | iPhone | 10.00 |
+----+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Complete Java class:

```
package com.test1;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

/**
 * 
 * @author user2176499
 *
 */
public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        Map<String, Object> row = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("select * from Product where id=?", 1);

        System.out.println(row.getClass());
        System.out.println(row.keySet());
        System.out.println(row.values());
        System.out.println(row.containsKey("name"));
        System.out.println(row.get("name"));

        Iterator<String> iterator = row.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(key + " - " + row.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println("==================");

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Product where id=?", new Object[] { 1 },
                new RowMapper<Map<String, Object>>() {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        return Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("id", rs.getInt("id")), Map.entry("name", rs.getString("name")),
                                Map.entry("price", rs.getDouble("price")));
                    }
                });
        System.out.println(rows);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap
[id, name, price]
[1, iPhone, 10.00]
false
null
id - null
name - null
price - null
==================
[{name=iPhone, price=10.0, id=1}]
```

Spring Version: spring-jdbc-5.2.2-release

Comment: Same code worked in spring boot 2.2.4 release and mysql 8.0.19 configuration. what happens when you iterate the row.keySet() and do a row.get() with the key returned ?

Comment: @R.G, updated. Please refer to the updated output.

Comment: @ user2176499 . Could you please share the entire method / class that does the retrieval and printing . containsKey() is false and at the same time Iterator shows the key , but value is null.

Comment: @R.G Updated to full class.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue and prints correctly. Hope someone knowledgable help you out.

Comment: @R.G Thank you for trying.